# How to define a block with 2 inputs?

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I am kind of new to c++, so I am not sure where to put the definition of the vector
and the "input_sizes.push_back" in the .cc file. (after de include? after the sptr? in the definition of the sptr? in a new method?). Here is the "official" example:

-- A block with 2 inputs (float and double) and 1 output --

```
std::vector<int> input_sizes;
input_sizes.push_back(sizeof(float));
input_sizes.push_back(sizeof(double));

gnuradio::block("my block",
gr_make_io_signaturev(2, 2, input_sizes),
gr_make_io_signature(1, 1, sizeof(float)))
```

The example can be found in [1](https://github.com/guruofquality/grextras/wiki/Blocks-Coding-Guide#wiki-id4/) :

Answer (score 0):

Some people in Discuss-gnuradio@gnu.org mailing list answer me.The simplest answer (also the one I used) was:
`gr_make_io_signature2 (2, 2, sizeof(float), sizeof(double))`

:)  :)